# Initial Angular JS controller values not appearing

Tags: angularjs

I worked through the tutorial on the Angular website and understood it mostly, and now I'm trying to fuss around and experiment on my own, so I cloned angular-seed and am trying to get even the most basic things going but failing.

Here's my view1.html

```
<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
<p>{{$ctrl.testvalue}} Hello </p>
```

And here's my view1.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {
  this.testvalue = "Hey there";
}]);
```

The only things I have changed are adding the 2nd line in the html file, and the testvalue in the controller section of the module.

When I load the webpage, the text "Hey there" does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: please add plunker.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Use `{{testvalue}}` in the view and `$scope.testvalue = "Hey there";` in the controler (don't forget to inject $scope in the controller)

Comment: @JanP , that worked. If you submit this as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to not use scope then you can go by `controllerAs` syntax in your route config:

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.testvalue = "Hey there";
}]);
```

And in your route config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
     templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
     controller: 'View1Ctrl',
     controllerAs: 'vm'
 });
}])
```

And then in your html:

```
<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>
<p>{{vm.testvalue}} Hello </p>
```

Of course you could just add controllerAs in your route config and it works too.

Comment: I am not necessarily looking to avoid using scope, I'm just not entirely sure what that means. If I'm not using best practice, please feel free to educate me.

Comment: @stumpbeard you're following the right pattern, you're just missing the controllerAs key in your config as I mentioned

Comment: @stumpbeard ControllerAs mechanism is very handy if you use nested controllers in your view. In that case use `controllerAs: 'View1'` and `View2`. That makes it possible to have the same variable name in both controllers and address them in your view separately by `{{View1.testvalue}}` and `{{View2.testvalue}}`.

Comment: Upon further investigation, this method has good application for my uses. Some questions: if I make for example, an input with ng-model, would the value be vm.testInput as opposed to $ctrl.testInput?

Comment: Why did the tutorial have such widespread use of $ctrl in the views? I'm having trouble replicating their functionality.

Comment: that is one of the initial steps of migrating Angular 1.x to 2. using $ctrl makes it easier to get there @stumpbeard